# Go's runtime library document out of date?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

So, I'm working on parsing a  POST using GO.  What I want is the body of the post, so I try the following (`r` is of type `*http.Request` in this context):

```
var body io.Reader
var d []byte
body = r.Body.Reader
body.Read( d)
```

However, this results in a compilation error:

```
Compile error: <file>:44: 
    r.Body.Reader undefined (type io.ReadCloser has no field or method Reader)
```

Odd.  I could have sworn that it was defined in the docs... Ah! [here it is](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadCloser).

Now, I'm fairly new to Go, but this smells a little odd -- what have I screwed up?

Comment: Crap.  I misread the documents.  It's `io.ReadCloser` *is-a* `Reader` not *has-a* `Reader`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your link, the doc for a `ReadCloser` is:

```
type ReadCloser interface {
    Reader
    Closer
}
```

What this is telling you, is that a ReadCloser interface is composed of a `Reader` and a `Closer` functionality. It IS both. That means the `ReadCloser` takes on those interface definitions. They are not actually members, the way you are accessing them.

A `Reader` is:

```
type Reader interface {
    Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

So that means you should be accessing `Read` like this:

```
body = r.Body
body.Read(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way interfaces are defined in Go documents, it looked like it was a "has-a" relationship.  It's actually an "is-a" relationship, so the following code does what I want:

```
var d []byte
r.Body.Read(d)
```

Comment: Actually  its both. It can have function definitions (as members), and can compose other interfaces similar to inheritance. When a type is being checked...then the it is looked at as "has a" to see that it satisfies the interface.